# How can I Update item on Vaadin's Grid without putting explicitly all fields on it?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I try to create regular CRUD operations on `Grid` table for `User` entity - which is like this:

```
public class User {
    private id;
    private String name
    private Role role;
}
```

with appropriate getters and setters.

- The `Grid` should have 2 fields: `name` and `role.name`.
- I want to create a data `IndexedContainer`for that `Grid`
- I want to make updates - which will bind container's data to `User` model.

  - by model I mean `User` entity, not Vaadin's internal model

How can I do that? I have problem with 2 things:

- creating appropriate listener
- binding existing `User` model to row/index in data `IndexedContainer`

Explanation:

- `IndexedContainer` has `itemId` property, where  I can left user's id for future binding on update. But after creating `ValueChangeListener` on the `IndexedContainer` I found that I have no access to its `itemId` field.
- So I tried with `CommitHandler` in `EditorFieldGroup` (the field of `Grid` object) and there is the same scenario, but I see `itemId` property in debug made, but I can't reach it because it is a private field. I can of course get it through reflection - but I don't think that this is a good way to do that.

Maby there is some other way to update `User` model from `Grid` tabular data?

Maby I should add `User` id field to grid as regular `IndexedContainer` property, but make it hidden and read-only? But I wonder if it is safe and there's no threat that someone change frontend form and can update `User` with id not presented on the `Grid` table.

If anyone know what is the best practice on that typical case, please let me know. I will be very glad for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using editable grid component you will need to use a `FieldGroup`. In your case you can use `BeanFieldGroup`. If you have right getter/setter methods the `BeanFieldGroup` can take care of updating your entity instance when user changes and saves data from grid. Following is a small code snippet:

```java
grid.setEditorFieldGroup(
    new BeanFieldGroup<Person>(User.class));
```

Additionally you can add validations for your `User` entity by using standard `@NotNull`, `@Size`, `@Min`, `@Max` etc.

For more check out book of vaadin website. Hope this helps!

Comment: it just works! Thanks! But there is some issue: I have 2 nested fields, which points to the same related Entity, but hold its different value. When I do it this way - my Bean is updated - but on those fields - there is same value (in particular - the second one). Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: OK, I figured it out. It's because those 2 fields pointed on the same related object.